# How to pile drive hooked rebar

Tags: retaining-wall, rebar

I use a combination of a sledgehammer and jackhammer to drive [straight] rebar for use in retaining walls . The former gets the stakes started and the latter really drives them home with authority.  How can a J-hook rebar be driven with similar force as the jackhammer provides for the straight stakes ?

[image]

Comment: If needing a jack hammer to drive them down, at 3/8" would use the straight ones and bend them after.  The bent ones probably not made for hard ground.  Not sure if a sledge would deform the bend too much.

Comment: Try making a wood "socket" to fit over the end of the bar and give you something to pound on.

Comment: @HotLicks That's a good idea - i was looking for an appropriate "adapter" but it does not exist: so that's what DIY is all about

Comment: re-bar driven into the ground for a retaining wall? -  I hope that's a temporary wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tent stake driver that has a gigantic 5+ inch diameter. This is another potential option besides the hand-held post-hole driver suggested by @Jasen

[image]

Comment: This won't help in case of the J-hook the asker is trying to drive in though!

Comment: @MiG the asker and the answerer are the same in this particular case. ;)

Comment: Good point :) I don't see how that particular item will help though, considering the top of the hook is a much larger diameter bend, rather than just the pointy tip if it were a straight bar.

Comment: @MiG the diameter here is sufficient - that's why I am looking specifically at this one

Comment: @WestCoastProjects I'm not sure if it will work well. You'd have to put that thing on top of the bend, and because the hammering force is not in line with the rest of the bar, it will turn that 180 degree turn into a curl. Unless that's no problem of course.

Comment: I understand the concern. This one is probably actually too wide. But the general concept has actually worked out ok. The rebar is firm enough to handle pounding by a manual sledgehammer and *act* like a rigid pole even when not hitting it directly along its spine.  Hitting it with a sledgehammer is actually likely to be *easier* since I can do a better job of maintaining a consistent proper alignment with the rod ( I'm not particularly precise at hammer and nail let alone sledge and rebar)

Answer (score 1):

A: get someone to hold it for you. then hit it with the sledge hammer

your assistant will probably want a hard-hat and tongs or long pliers.

B: use a "Y post" driver. to start them.

Comment: A.  A sledge does not even begin to touch the effectivness of the pile driver.   B) I'll look up what a Y post driver is and get back.  Update: I found a smallish y-post driver from Zoro.   Too small for the 3/8 rebar and it's a 1/4" shank which is for a small hand-held hammer-drill not for my jackhammer.   Unless my google foo improves I'll continue on the path of planning to construct an adapter out of wood

Comment: I'm thinking the manual type,  a tube with handles both sides and one end blocked

Comment: Assuming you're referring to the fence post drivers -  I've been eye-ing one of those at the local Ace. I have been assuming the head diameter were a wee bit too small but will double check.  The J-hooks are a bit over 3 1/2 inches at  1/2 inch below the head - so a 3 3/4 to 4inch diameter driver would be best. Will check at Ace in couple of days . Update: "wee bit small" is correct : the manual posthole driver is 3 inches

Comment: Another update: a 4inch diameter driver does exist - but it's $238 which obliterates the budget. will look more

Comment: in the photo it looked like 2"  so that may not work.

Comment: ah good point: I just measured against J-hooks I have at the house now but they're 1/2" rebar. the ones I'm eying are 3/8 " so a 3" diameter shaft should work.

Comment: Depending on the durability of the tong / pliers, their working length and the strength of your helping hand, you could clamp down on the straight part of the J-hook real hard, then hammer the pliers themselves right up against the J-hook. The force will transfer onto the hook that way (without turning the J-hook into an O-hook). Don't do this if it might damage the tool though.